# Localhost redirected you too many times. How to Prevent user to access page from admin

Tags: php, session

So I want to prevent user to not access page from admin page.

user page = index.php

admin page = indexp.php

If session user try to open indexp.php, I want it to be redirected to index.php
and if session admin try to open index.php, I want it to be redirected to index.php

**indexp.php**

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_SESSION['access']) != 'admin'){
  header('location:index.php');
 }
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['kelass'])){
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];     
    $kelas = $_SESSION['kelass']; 
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM piket WHERE 
kelas = '$kelas' ORDER BY tgl_piket DESC");

}else {
header('location:login.php');
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['access']) != 'user'){
    header('location:indexp.php');
  }

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['kelass'])){
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $kelas = $_SESSION['kelass'];
    if (date('D')=='Mon') {
      $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM siswa where hari='senin' and kelas='$kelas' ORDER BY no ASC");
      $haridb="senin";
    }

    elseif (date('D')=='Tue') {
      $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM siswa where hari='selasa' and kelas='$kelas' ORDER BY no ASC");
      $haridb="selasa";
    }

    elseif (date('D')=='Wed') {
      $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM siswa where hari='rabu' and kelas='$kelas' ORDER BY no ASC");
      $haridb="rabu";
    }

    elseif (date('D')=='Thu') {
      $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM siswa where hari='kamis' and kelas='$kelas' ORDER BY no ASC");
      $haridb="kamis";
    }

    elseif (date('D')=='Fri') {
      $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM siswa where hari='jumat' and kelas='$kelas' ORDER BY no ASC");
      $haridb="jumat";
    }


    }else {
      header('location:login.php');
    }
```

**loginproc.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
    $gettype = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    echo $gettype['access'];
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($check > 0) {
        if($gettype['access']=='user'){
            $_SESSION['access'] = 'user';
            $_SESSION['username'] = $gettype['username'];
            header('location:index.php');


        }
        else if ($gettype['access']=='admin') {
            $_SESSION['access']== 'admin';
            $_SESSION['username'] = $gettype['username'];
            $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
            header('location:indexp.php');


        }
     }
    }
```

It won't work with this code

If I login with admin it says localhost redirected you too many times
and if I login with user I can still access indexp.php

thanks in advance

Comment: verify what your session variables contain

Comment: i fixed it by deleting else {
header('location:login.php');
but if i access page without login, it'll "redirected too many times"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> isset($_SESSION['access']) != 'admin'

This line will always be true since `isset()` returns a **boolean**.

It will be interpreted like this:

`false != 'admin'` or `true != 'admin'`, in literary: is false different from the word 'admin'? is true different from the word 'admin'? in both cases it will be: **true**

You should compare like this:

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['access']) && $_SESSION['access'] != 'admin')
{
//other codes...
}
```

And inside **index.php**, check this way:

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['access']) && $_SESSION['access']!= 'user'){
    header('location:indexp.php');
  }
```

Good luck